# Vb.net nesting repeater 3 levels Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I am trying to nest 3 repeaters to display FAQs

Category

--sub Category

----Question

The first 2 repeaters are fine but when I try to add the third I get

*BC30506: Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.*

[image: aspx file]
I cant get the aspx file to paste in on this editor so above is a screen grab

and the vb file is

```
Partial Class ContactTest
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public Conn As New SqlConnection(Utils.connString)
Sub Page_load()
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Conn.Open()
        FAQCatRep.DataSource = db.Open.DS("select * from FAQ_Category", Conn)
        FAQCatRep.DataBind()
        Conn.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub FAQCatRep_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles FAQCatRep.ItemDataBound
    Select Case e.Item.ItemType
        Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem

            Dim repFaqSub As Repeater = e.Item.FindControl("FAQSubCatRep")

            repFaqSub.DataSource = db.Open.DS("select * from FAQ_Sub_Category where Categoryid=" + e.Item.DataItem("ID").ToString(), Conn)
            repFaqSub.DataBind()

    End Select
End Sub

Protected Sub FAQSubCatRep_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles FAQSubCatRep.ItemDataBound
    Select Case e.Item.ItemType
        Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem

            Dim repFaqQs As Repeater = e.Item.FindControl("QuestionRep")

            repFaqQs.DataSource = db.Open.DS("select * from FAQ where SubCatid=" + e.Item.DataItem("ID").ToString(), Conn)
            repFaqQs.DataBind()

    End Select
End Sub
```

End Class

The error occurs on the FAQSubCatRep_ItemDataBound function.

Does anyone have any ideas?

thanks

Got it working. Added a Literal to the aspx inside the second repeater to store the sub category id and changed the FAQCatRep_ItemDataBound function to

```
   Protected Sub FAQCatRep_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles FAQCatRep.ItemDataBound
    Select Case e.Item.ItemType
        Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem

            Dim repFaqSub As Repeater = e.Item.FindControl("SubFAQSubCatRep")

            repFaqSub.DataSource = db.Open.DS("select * from FAQ_Sub_Category where Categoryid=" + e.Item.DataItem("ID").ToString(), Conn)
            repFaqSub.DataBind()

            For Each subcat As RepeaterItem In repFaqSub.Items
                Select Case subcat.ItemType
                    Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem
                        Dim qsub As Repeater = CType(subcat.FindControl("QuestionRep"), Repeater)
                        qsub.DataSource = db.Open.DS("select * from FAQ where SubCatid=" + CType(subcat.FindControl("SubCatgeoryIDltl"), Literal).Text, Conn)
                        qsub.DataBind()

                End Select
            Next
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I can put  Public WithEvents FAQSubCatRep As Repeater at the top and get rid of the error but the function is never called

Comment: ok, still got no idea what is wrong but managed to get it working by deleting FAQSubCatRep_ItemDataBound function and changing the FAQCatRep_ItemDataBound function to the above